# Mass Compile Cobol code in IBM i (aka OS/400, iSeries)

Tags: shell, ibm-midrange, cobol

I am new to COBOL and AS/400 IBM iSeries world, and am interested in best practices used in this community.

How do people perform batch compilation of all COBOL members, or multiple members at once?

I see that AS/400 source files are organized in libraries, file
objects, and members. How do you detect which file members are COBOL src
 code to be compiled? Can you get the member file type (which should be CBL
 in this case) via some qshell command?

Thanks,
Akku

Answer (score 4):

Common PDM manual method:

Probably the simplest and most widely used method would be to use PDM (Program Development Manager) in a "green-screen" (5250-emulation) session.  This allows you to manually select every program you wish to compile.  It may not be quite the answer you were looking for, but it may be the most widely used, due to its simple approach, and leaving decisions in the developer's hands.

People commonly use the Start PDM command `STRPDM`, which provides a menu where you can select an option to work with lists of Libraries, Objects (Files), or Members.  (Personally, I prefer to use the corresponding commands directly, `WRKLIBPDM`, `WRKOBJPDM`, or `WRKMBRPDM`.)  At each of these levels you can filter the list by pressing F17 (shift F5).

F18 (shift F6) allows you to set the option to Compile in Batch.  This means that each individual compile will be submitted to a job queue, to compile in its own job.  You can also specify which job description you would like to use, which will determine which job queue the jobs are placed on.  Some job queues may be single threaded, while others might run multiple jobs at once.  You can custom-define your own PDM options with F16.

If you chose to start at the library level, you can enter option 12 next to each library you wish to work with its objects (source files).

At the object level, you would want to view only objects of type *FILE, and attribute 'PF-SRC' (or concievably 'PF38-SRC').  You can then enter option 12 beside any source file you wish to work with its members.

At the member level, you might want to filter to type `*CBL*` because (depending on how things have been done on your system) COBOL members could be CBL, CBLLE, SQLCBL, SQLCBLE, or even System/38 or /36 variants.  Type option 14 (or a custom-defined option) next to each member you wish to compile.  You can repeat an option down the list with F13 (shift F1).

This method uses manual selection, and does not automatically select ALL of your COBOL programs to be compliled.  But it does allow you to submit large numbers of compiles at a time, and uses programmer discretion to determine which members to select, and what options to use.

Answer (score 3):

Many (if not most) developers on IBM i are generally not very familiar with qshell.  Most of us write automation scripts in CL.  A few renegades like myself may also use REXX, but sadly this is rare.  It's not too often that we would want to re-compile all programs in the system.  Generally we only compile programs that we are working with, or select only those affected by some file change.

Compiling everything might not be a simple problem.  Remember some libraries or source files might simply be archival copies of old source, which you might not really want to compile, or that might not compile successfully anymore. You would want to distinguish which members are COBOL copybooks, rather than programs.  With ILE, you would want to distinguish which members should be compiled as programs, modules, or service programs.  You may need to compile modules before compiling programs that bind with them.  Those modules might not necessarily have been written in COBOL, or COBOL modules might be bound into ILE programs in other languages, perhaps CL or RPG.

So how would a full system recompile be automated in a CL program?  You could get a list of all source files on they system with `DSPOBJD *ALL/*ALL *FILE OUTPUT(*FILE) OUTFILE( ___ )`.  The output file contains a file attribute column to distinguish which objects are source files.  Your CL program could read this, and for each source file, it could generate a file of detailed member information with `DSPFD &lib/&file TYPE(*MBR) OUTPUT(*FILE) OUTFILE( ___ )`.  That file contains member type information, which could help you determine which members were COBOL.  From there you could `RTVOBJD` to figure out whether it was a program, module, and/or service program.

You may also need to know the options for how individual programs, modules, or service programs were compiled.  I often solve this by creating a source file, which I generally call BUILD, with a member for each object that needs special handling.  This member could be CL, but I often use REXX.  In fact I might be tempted to do the whole thing in REXX for its power as a dynamic interpreted language. But that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @WarrenT: A lot of time passed and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but: Did you integrate some date-difference check between source members and object files in REXX, so your approach feels a tiny little bit like the UNIX make? If yes, I'd be interested to share your approach.